# Huawei Map Kit integration. Error: Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.huawei.hms.maps.SupportMapFragment'

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Error: Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.huawei.hms.maps.SupportMapFragment'

Using android appcompat dependecy in their project. like below,
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SupportMapFragment is extending androidx.fragmnet.app.Fragment

If you are not using AndroidX please  go for MapFragment which is extending android.support.v4.app.Fragment

import com.huawei.hms.maps.MapFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

MapFragment mapFragment= (MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);